How to represent a parabola with the form $y = c_1 y_1 + c_2 y_2 + c_3 y_3$
The curve which passes through the three points $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, and $(x_3, y_3)$ is given by $y = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2$.
It seems that this curve can be represented by another form: $y = c_1 y_1 + c_2 y_2 + c_3 y_3$, where $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$ are independent from (does not contain) $y_1$, $y_2$, and $y_3$ (But $x$ can be contained).
I am wondering how to obtain the values of $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$?
I will appreciate it if you could help me with this question.
Note
I have come up with the following solution:
The condition that the three points are passed by the parabola is equivalent to the following system of equations:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_1 & x_1^2 \\
1 & x_2 & x_2^2 \\
1 & x_3 & x_3^2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 \\
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Let $A$ be the matrix on the right-hand side of the equation.
Since the determinant of $A$ is the Vandermonde determinant, which is non-zero, $A$ is invertible.
Therefore, the solution is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 \\
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
= A^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
y_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Let the first row of $A^{-1}$ be $a'_0$, the second row be $a'_1$, and the third row be $a'_2$.
Then, we obtain $a_0 = a'_0 \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix}$, $a_1 = a'_1 \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix}$, and $a_2 = a'_2 \begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix}$.
Here, let $Y$ be $\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{pmatrix}$.
The original equation was $y = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2$, so by substituting the above, we obtain the following equation:
$$
y = a'_0 Y + a'_1 x Y + a'_2 x^2 Y
\Leftrightarrow y =(a'_0 + a'_1 x + a'_2 x^2) Y
$$
Therefore, the next thing is to calculate $a'_0 + a'_1 x + a'_2 x^2$.
I am wondering how to do this. Is calculating the inverse of $A$ to obtain $a'_0$, $a'_1$, and $a'_2$ the only way?
Or is there a simpler way?

$y=c_1y_1+c_2y_2+c_3y_3$ is a constant function. Where "It is known"?

@azif00 Thank you for your comment and sorry for my ambiguity. To clarify, I wanted to say that $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$ does not contain $y_1$, $y_2$, and $y_3$ (But are allowed to contain $x$). I have revised my question based on your suggestion.

Use the Lagrange interpolating polynomial. The explicit expression is
$$
y=c_1(x)y_1+c_2(x)y_2+c_3(x)y_3, \tag{1}
$$
where
\begin{align}
c_1(x)&=\frac{(x-x_2)(x-x_3)}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3)}, \tag{2.1} \\
c_2(x)&=\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_3)}{(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3)}, \tag{2.2} \\
c_3(x)&=\frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)}. \tag{2.3}
\end{align}

Thank you for your answer. I have learned the generalized form of polynomial interpolation and will continue to look more deeply about the background of my question.
